# What's the best way to populate a new row in a database?

Tags: c#, database, sql, sql-server

Is it possible to add a new row to a database using DataSet? When I created a new DataSet and dragged the table from the database I could see that in the DataSet methods there was one called *insert* that in the preview showed a parameterized query almost like a stored procedure to insert data.

However, when I create a new object of that DataSet in the methods there is nothing called *insert* or nothing that says I can insert the data from a DataSet into a database.

Answer (score 1):

From [Msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233812.aspx), you need to use the `TableAdapter` that is created:

> If you do not have an instance available, instantiate the TableAdapter
>   you want to use.

Example:

```
NorthwindDataSetTableAdapters.RegionTableAdapter regionTableAdapter = 
    new NorthwindDataSetTableAdapters.RegionTableAdapter();

regionTableAdapter.Insert(5, "NorthWestern");
```

Check the above link for more examples.

Comment: I tnink that I will try EF since i'ts really straightforward and allows to use the tables as classes which is really really useful. However I can't find any info about parameterization when using EF. Does the commands INSERT and so on have built-in parameterization?